# how to merge two data.frame and mark matched found or not

Tags: r, merge

I have two data.frame, df1 and df2 that look like following:
df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

df1 and df2 can be build using code:

```
df1<-structure(list(Var = c("SEX", "SEXSP", "FEMCBP", "FEMCBPSP", 
"RACE", "RACESP", "ETHNIC", "INITVER", "IFCDT", "STDYPART"), 
    Label = c("Gender:", "If other, please specify:", "If female, please select one of the following:", 
    "If other, please specify:", "Race:", "If other, please specify:", 
    "Ethnicity:", "Version of protocol the subject consented to when subject started the study:", 
    "Date Informed Consent was signed by subject to start the study (DD MMM YYYY):", 
    "Study Arm:")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df2<- structure(list(Var2 = c("RACE", "RACESP", "ETHNIC", "IFCDT", 
"STDYPART"), Label2 = c("Race:", "If other, please specify:", 
"Ethnicity:", "Date Informed Consent was signed by subject to start the study (DD MMM YYYY):", 
"Study Arm:")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to merge those two together and see whether we can find df1 in df2. I would like to get sth that looks like this:
[image]

what should I do?

```
df3<-merge(df1, df2, by.x=var, by.y=var2)

and?
```

Comment: In your `by.x` and `by.y`, it needs to be a string and the column names should match correct case i.e. `transform(merge(df1, df2, by.x= 'Var', by.y='Var2', all.x = TRUE), matched = c("N", "Y")[1 + !is.na(Label2)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining your data frames, write the code below. all.x means after matching it by the key i.e by.x and by.y, fetch all records from the left table (x)

```
df <- merge(df1,df2,by.x = "Var",by.y = "Var2",all.x = TRUE)
```

Create a column which shows if there was a match

```
df$Matched <- ifelse(!is.na(df$Label2),"Y","N")
```